# CSS: Get a center-positioned fluid image background

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

This has been annoying me now for a few hours as I keep fiddling around with the code and don't seem to be getting anywhere at all.

I really like the way that this website has a fluid image background:

[Here](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/)

I have downloaded the code and am not currently trying to make a slideshow, but instead a single image background that when you play around with the size of your browser expands and contracts the same way as in the website.

If i take the code that they use in their CSS and apply it to my own image I keep getting this instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/9cpz4gua/

```
body{
        background-image:url(https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg?width=960);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;

        }
```

Could someone please advise me what to do in order to get my background image to expand and contract about the center as the website does?

Comment: do you want it in css only, with some JS it would be much easier? and, do you want your image to be body's background? other options would be easier and better

Comment: Honestly whatever the easiest way is, I just want a blank webpage except for an image such as the one I linked to be on the background so when you change the size of the browser the background image proportions are the same as the one in the website if that makes sense.

Comment: i'll post now a response with a fiddle link for you, you'll have 1 problem that you'll have to deal with, the image's proportions, i'll leave this one for you! you have many ways to deal with it so i'm not gonna insist on any of them ways

Comment: Thank you, be really helpful!

Comment: @OmarElDon still looking for help please :)

Comment: there you are!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer, it may not be the easiest or the most complete but it give a very beautiful looking result that answers your question

Basically, you create a new `div` directly under your `body`
 and style it this way:

```
.bgimg {
    z-index: 1;
    background: url(http://dondev.ovh/light_abstract.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/bet1y4jn/)

This is a css only answer, you can use JavaScript alongside for better result.

Regards

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. Could I ask why Javascript would give me a better result, and whether there is anything I should worry about if I use it this way?

Comment: @SteveJobs you don't have to worry about anything but the pics proportions.. you need to know the images you're using for the background

if you're having a scroll-able page consider changing `position: absolute ` to `position: fixed`

Javascript won't exactly give better looking results but more flexible one

Comment: And finally when you talk about the pic proportions, what would you recommend doing? Say I have a roughly landscape 1920x1080 pixel image do I need to do anything?

Comment: always use 5:4 or 16:9 proportioned images as these give the best results... if you want to have more freedom, you'll have to use js to define the sizes

Comment: So to clarify, use 5:4 or 19:9 proportioned images and I don't have to edit the code above at all? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: in major cases, and landscape oriented browsers

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to have your image always fill the page, just remove some things from your own style to achieve the "cover" effect.

Try this:

```
body{
    background-image:url(https://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/03/smiley-face.jpg?width=960);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9cpz4gua/2/

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the desired effect for me as when I try it on my .html file and resize the browser it gets to a point where when I make the browser small enough there is a lot of whitespace, which isn't what is in the example given above.